# Import framenet from nltk.corpus(.reader) in python2.7: ImportError

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk, importerror

I noticed that I cannot import framenet from nltk.corpus.reader or from nltk.corpus and understood that it is available in newer versions of NLTK.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.__version__
'3.0a2'
```

But the nltk.downloader shows an entry for framenet_v15 and in the filesystem I have a directory framnet_v15.
So why can I not import it?

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import framenet
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name framenet
>>> from nltk.corpus.reader import framenet
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name framenet
```

As you can see: framenet corpus is already installed

[image: framenet corpus is already installed]

Comment: Do you have sample code?

Comment: what is the output of nltk.__version__.  You need 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from nltk.corpus.reader import framenet
```

**Installation**

1. Download [NLTK 3.0](http://nltk.org/nltk3-alpha/nltk-3.0a2.tar.gz)
2. tar -xzvf ntlk-3.0a3.tar.gz
3. cd nltk-3.0a3/
4. sudo python setup.py install

**Execution**

> ./example.py

Comment: this raises an error:  `raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions matching the version for %s' % req)
pip.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No distributions matching the version for nltk==3.0`

Comment: I've updated my answer to walk you through installing NTLK 3.

Comment: this helped me install NLTK 3.0 to python2.7. But I still cannot import framenet. I updated my question.

Comment: Do you have a 64-bit python installation? If so replace with a 32-bit version. A bug exists in the 64-bit build.   http://morkrispil.wordpress.com/2013/05/04/install-nltk-on-64-bit-windows/